# Play 2.3, activator does not work

Tags: playframework-2.0, typesafe-activator

I downloaded Play 2.3 from the official site. There was an archive with 3 files:

```
activator
activator-launch-1.2.0.jar
activator.bat
```

I extracted them into /Users/vbezhenar/Applications/activator-1.2.0-minimal and added this path to $PATH.

Now I type:

```
% pwd                                                      
/Users/vbezhenar/Projects/test/play
% which activator                                          
/Users/vbezhenar/Applications/activator-1.2.0-minimal/activator
% activator new p1 play-scala
```

and get error

```
unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.activator#activator-launcher;1.2.0: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
  (see /Users/vbezhenar/.sbt/boot/update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve activator-launcher 1.2.0
```

File .sbt/boot/update.log - http://pastebin.com/3b5LAz7X

I don't understand why it tries to download this launcher if it's already in the distribution. Is it bug or I did something wrong?

I tried to remove ~/.sbt ~/.ivy2 but it didn't help.

Comment: I have the same issue with minimal package of the activator. You can download the full version from [here] (http://typesafe.com/platform/getstarted). It works for me.

Comment: Thanks, full distribution works fine. I guess that new JAR artifacts are not deployed to the public repositories yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seem to work now. Is it possible it was a transient problem with the repository server:
 https://twitter.com/scala_sbt/status/473080577474981888

If anyone else is seeing this please let us know on the activator issue tracker:
https://github.com/typesafehub/activator/issues

Comment: I performed a clean install and everything now works as expected.

Comment: I had the same issue - I received a bunch of "servers overloaded" a few minutes ago.  Twice.  Trying again and it seems to be working